# Can I set an erlang node to 'hidden', or set 'connect_all' to false, after a node has already been created?

Tags: erlang

I am looking to dynamically set an erlang node to 'hidden' or set 'connect_all' after the node has already been created. Is this possible in erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an undocumented `net_kernel:hidden_connect_node(NodeName)` function that can be used on a per-connection basis for `NodeName` not to share all the connection details of the caller.

There is no guarantee related to its long term support, but that's currently the only way to do things dynamically.

Comment: how do you learn of these undocumented functions? I've come across a few and I just don't know what to make of it when I see a function in code that I can't find in docs.

Comment: Mostly I have read some OTP source code to know how it all works, and also have contributed a few patches here and there over time.

Comment: It does seem odd that some of the basic erl shell flags don't have documented functions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE (AND WRITE AWESOME ERLANG BOOKS) for sharing this gem of knowledge. I would also like to highlight how it has been particularly useful in my specific case :

Context :

- I have several machines that host an Erlang node running my OTP application
- The nodes are configured in a wireless peer-to-peer setup
- For testing purposes, I would like to observe the behaviour of the cluster when multi-hop is required from a node A to another node B.

So far my best (and only) solution has been to physically move around the nodes such that they can only reach neighbours in range of their Wi-Fi antenna.

Bottom line for those that are in situations similar to what I have described, this is a very handy function for clustering nodes without completely removing the default transitive behaviour.